# MediaType is always application/json in MessageBodyWriter in Quarkus with quarkus-resteasy-reactive

Tags: resteasy, quarkus

Im migrating a JAX-RS application to Quarkus using the `resteasy-reactive-jackson` extension. One of the resource methods should return an Excel document if the Accept-header is `application/vnd.ms-excel`. The Excel document is created in a `MessageBodyWriter<>`. This works as expected in the old application (KumuluzEE, Jersey).

My requests are successfully routed to the resource method, the Accept-header is present but when the response entity arrives at my implementation of `isWriteable` in the `MessageBodyWriter<>` the mediaType parameter is always `application/json`. I have tried implementing a `ServerMessageBodyWriter<>` but that did not make any difference.

Any ideas of whats going on?

Im using Quarkus v2.2.

---

Edit 2:

The service interface is in it's own Maven module:

```
@Path("")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@RegisterRestClient
@RegisterClientHeaders
public interface MyResource {

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
//  @Produces({"application/vnd.ms-excel", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON}) // Works
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "application/vnd.ms-excel"}) // Does not work
    Response getData(@PathParam("id") Long id);

}
```

The resource implementation and MessageBodyWriter:

```
public class MyResourceImpl implements MyResource {

    @Context
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders; // getAcceptableMediaTypes() returns mediatypes
                             // matching Accept-header as expected

    @Override
    public Response getData(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        return Response.ok().entity(new MyData()).build();
    }

}
```

```
@Provider
@Produces({"application/vnd.ms-excel"})
public class ExcelMessageBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<MyData> {

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> aClass, Type type, 
                               Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        // mediaType is always MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE when JSON 
        // is listed first in @Produces in service interface
        return aClass == MyData.class && mediaType.getType().equals("application")
                && mediaType.getSubtype().equals("vnd.ms-excel");
    }

    ...
}
```

Changing `@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "application/vnd.ms-excel"})` on the resource method to `@Produces({"application/vnd.ms-excel", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})` solved my problem. This can't be the expected behaviour?

Comment: So basically you are saying that the Accept header is not being taken into account?

Comment: Yes, when JSON is the first media type in the @Produces-annotation on the resource method it seems to get selected as media type in the MessageBodyWriter. I double checked this a moment ago with same results as yesterday.
I got my application working so I guess my question is if there is something i've misunderstand or if this could be a bug?

Comment: Can you try version `2.4.1.Final` of Quarkus? A vaguely remember fixing a similar issue.

Comment: Did try with 2.5.0.Final, unfortunately it still behaves the same way.

Comment: Can you open an issue please?

Comment: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/22119